# Trying to exploit SQL injection

Tags: mariadb, webserver, sql-injection, penetration-testing, penetration-tools

I am trying to exploit a SQLI and I don't understand why my "group_concat" doesn't work.

I managed to extract the name of the database ("games") :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tomrn.png)

But when I try to extract the tables from this database, I have a syntax error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWIYe.png)

Why do I have this syntax error?

PS: This is being done on an hacking learning plateform so no nasty illegal stuff going on.

Comment: please, no pictures of text ... add the text instead

Comment: Welcome! Can you please [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? [See here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the ",333..." stuff?  that is a syntax error, and so you get a syntax error.